# What's the referent of this 'that'?

Tags: pronouns

> "Charlie's in Romania studying dragons, and Bill's in Africa doing something for Gringotts[bank]," said Ron. "Did you hear about Gringotts? It's been all over the Daily Prophet, but I don't suppose you get **that** with the Muggles - someone tried to rob a high security vault."
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What’s the referent for *that*? I’m puzzling whether it is for the newspaper (Daily Prophet), or the news about Gringotts bank.

Comment: I've just found this question. If *the Muggles* is a newspaper, then this *that* must refer to the news (about Gringotts), otherwise, the clause *I don't suppose you get that with the Muggles* will not make any sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be the news, which of course would not appear in a Muggle journal; but I think it's the newspaper. It would very natural for me to say

> I read about Musial's death in the *St. Louis Post-Dispatch*, but I don't suppose you get that in Korea.

But if I were speaking about the likelihood of Korean media reporting the news item, I would be more likely to say something like

> I read about Musial's death in the *St. Louis Post-Dispatch*, but I don't suppose that gets noticed (*or* reported *or* talked about) in Korea.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely the newspaper. "That" as an object will almost always refer back to whatever object was last mentioned in the sentence.

Comment: "the newspaper" being *The Daily Prophet*, of course.